# Date Select boxs values convert to SQL data base date type value

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, date, datetime

My web site have three select box which are year, month and date. Those selector boxes values are like this.

- Year box value - 1992
- Moth box value - 02
- Date box value - 05

I want to convert to store my SQL data base in date type column.

First I tied to give directly like this to INSERT of sql databse. It is also not working.

```
$year . '-' . $month . '-' . $date
```

I tried to convent by following code but it get error.

```
$birthdate = Convert(varchar(30),$year . '-' . $month . '-' . $date,102);
```

Error:

Warning: main(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone.

Fatal error: Call to undefined function Convert()

PHP Code:

```
$birthdate = $d9 .'-' . $d10 . '-'. $d11;

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (you, usernames, usernamee, initials, firstname, midname, lastname, gender, birth_date, email, password, nic, phone, district, country, ip, signup, lastlogin, notescheck) 
            VALUES('$d1','$d2','$d3','$d4','$d5','$d6','$d7','$d8',$birthdate,'$d12','$p_hash','$d15','$d16','$d17','USA', '$ip',now(),now(),now())";
```

Comment: Why can't we put directly like this code to INSERT code $year . '-' . $month . '-' . $date

Comment: @Kumar I refer this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: There must be dozens of tutorials out there on this

Answer (score 0):

Simply append string:

```
$birthdate = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$date;

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (you, usernames, usernamee, initials, firstname, midname, lastname, gender, birth_date, email, password, nic, phone, district, country, ip, signup, lastlogin, notescheck) 
            VALUES('$d1','$d2','$d3','$d4','$d5','$d6','$d7','$d8','$birthdate','$d12','$p_hash','$d15','$d16','$d17','USA', '$ip',now(),now(),now())";
```

Comment: I did not get any errors but that value will not insert to database. Other values are normally insert to database.

Comment: I put it above.